# How to connect Python applications in Google Colab to a Spark cluster on AWS EMR

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-colaboratory, amazon-emr

I use Google Colab where I download,install Apache Spark as a single machine cluster and have used Pyspark to execute reasonably complex data processing applications. However, instead of using the single machine cluster that I can install in Colab, I would like to use a multi-machine Spark cluster running on AWS EMR, while still continuing to use the python applications that I have built and tested on Google Colab. How do I do this?

In Colab, I use the following strategy

```
!pip3 -q install pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# note UI port switched from default 4040 to 4050 to avoid clash with ngrok
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").config('spark.ui.port', '4050').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
textRDD = sc.textFile("Chronotantra.txt")
```

How should I configure the AWS EMR cluster and more important, how do I connect it with my Colab applications? Is there an IP address that I can get for the master machine in the EMR cluster and use the same IP address in ..

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('master-machine-IP').config('spark.ui.port', '4050').getOrCreate()
```

In Azure Databricks, I have seen that Jupyter notebooks can be easily connected to a cluster and I am looking for similar functionality in Colab.